# Which "for" loop has a better time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, linear-search

```
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
     if(i==number);
       break;
    }
```

OR

```
    for(i=0; ;i++)
    {
    if(i==number)
    break;
    }
```

Does removing the comparison part in the for loop effects the time complexity or not ?

Comment: First one is `O(n)`. Second one is `O(max(number))`.

Comment: it will terminate when i==number as there is a break statement. And its actually for an array which will have the "number" in it.

Comment: Thanks Eugene Sh., can you please explain how ?

Comment: The first one will run at most `n` times. The second will run at most the maximum possible value of `number`.

Comment: number is same in both the loops and are identical in everything except the comparison statement in for loop . Then they will have the same time complexity ?

Comment: `n` might be very small, while `number` is large. So it will be bounded by `n` and `number` wouldn't make any difference. But yeah, strictly speaking it should be `O(min(n, max(number))`

Comment: But if we can assume `number` can be in the same range as `n`, the complexity will be just the same.

Comment: The first one looks to be O(1), assuming C. Perhaps the semi-colon at the end of the if statement is a typo?

Comment: Yes , it is a typo

Answer (score 1):

You can't say which is faster precisely...

The time complexity for the first one is `O(min(n, number))` and the second is `O(number)`.

---

if n is bigger (or equal) than number, the first will be equal to the second.

- first: `O(number)` (as number is smaller than n, `min(n, number) = number`
- second:`O(number)`

---

if n is smaller than number, the first will be faster (as it also stops in n).

- first: `O(n)` (as n is smaller than number, `min(n, number) = n`
- second:`O(number)`

---

**in an overall view, the first will be faster.**

As you can see, removing the comparison inside the for look do make difference, what is quite obvious given the second case where their complexities become different.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, will the time also be same for both the loops ? Or some difference?

Comment: as I explained, the time will be different if number is bigger than n, otherwise the time complexity is the same